# Invoking a callback before or after showing a popover using angular-ui-bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, debouncing

I have a very simple code snipper in my page where I have a span. Hovering over this span displays a popover for which I am using angular-ui-bootstrap.

```
<span uib-popover="This is a popover from Akhilesh"
              ng-mouseenter="vm.logToConsole('I am trying hard...')"
              popover-trigger="mouseenter">Hover over me to see a popup..!!</span>
```

Basically I have written a function which makes and API call when the user hovers over this span. The problem here is that let's say I have 10 span tags one below the other and the user quickly moves from 1st span to 10th span (in the process hovering over all 8 spans in between), the API call will get triggered for all the spans. This is what I do not intend to have.

Any idea how can I implement the debounce functionality here?

Answer (score 0):

Use a delay, like one second, after the mouse enters the region, then if the mouse hasn't entered another area, make the API call.

Answer (score 0):

The popover-is-open attribute was added under the 0.13.4 release that can be used to watch the state of your popover like so:

```
<span uib-popover="This is a popover from Akhilesh"
          popover-is-open="vm.isOpen"
          popover-trigger="mouseenter">Hover over me to see a popup..!!</span>
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('isOpen', function() { });
```

But if you are just trying to keep the popovers from opening so quickly, consider using the popover-open-delay attribute.

Comment: The popover-open-delay attribute allows to control after how much time the popover will be shown. The idea here is to invoke a method after the popup is shown. So, let's say I set popover-open-delay to 300ms, the action should get executed after the popover gets displayed after 300ms.

Comment: This does NOT work for grids. setting popover-is-open="someValue" in the grid will make ALL popovers open at the same time.

Comment: @Jeff B Thats what I would expect to happen if you bind to a single property in your model.  When working with popovers in a grid, you need a backing model property for each row.  I've used an array with the row $index to accomplish this: popover-is-open="gridPopoverIsOpen[$index]".  To reset all popovers to closed when paging, set the gridPopoverIsOpen.length = 0. Similar strategy for accordion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191116/controlling-isopen-in-angular-ui-bootstap/34204451#34204451

Comment: @RobJ I see. Even then, it seems the support for callbacks is so minimal, using ng-mouseover for the OP's question seems to be just as good of a solution to me. Granted your way would be more readable for an outside user, as it is obvious you are relating the onOpen or onClose function with the popover itself, rather than an ambiguous ng-mouseover. You should add that info to your original answer btw =).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use, I found the best method is to simply add ng-mouseover, ng-click etc to the element and define a function to be called.

You can even create a variable and attach it to that objects scope on the fly to keep track of the state (open close).

Kind of hacky, but there is currently no way to define a function that is called on open and on close within ui-bootstrap popover.