# AngularUI: Popover open and close callbacks

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

So title says it all. I need some workaround for this since there's (currently) no attributes for popover like `popover-on-open` and `popover-on-close` where they would call/trigger the desired functions on such actions.
Can somebody help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question has been discussed in length here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722424/how-do-i-create-an-angularjs-ui-bootstrap-popover-with-html-content. I hope it helps

Comment: Finally, I've found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33609420/6062096